# Is "use" a negative word in the following sentence?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, connotation

I heard somebody say:

> I used my mother to find my socks.

The moment I heard it, my first impression was that it meant something bad — a rather negative word choice. Then I looked up *use* in the Oxford English dictionary and chose the following two entries which may suit here.

> 1. employ sth for a purpose; bring sth into service
> 2. exploit sb/sth selfishly

Which is correct here?

Likewise, in

> We have to use the police.

Is *use* here negative?

Comment: Who did you hear say that? Were they a native speaker?

Comment: "USE" is normally only used negatively when there is that sense of exploitation or abuse involved. I would say "finding socks" is not really that exploitative.

Comment: also I think this question may be more suited to: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not the word but its usage in the context that is objectionable. One does not 'employ', 'take the services of' or 'exploit' one's mother. Furthermore, when speaking of one's parents, a language more dignified than usual is necessary for purposes of **etiquette**. Something on the lines of *I asked my mother to help me find my socks* would be the least one might expect.

Comment: The police is a body for public service. As such in a sense, *use the police* should be fine: *If polite approach doesn't work, I may have to use the police!* (Take the services of the police).

Answer (score 1):

**[Use](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/use?q=use)** has a wide variety of meanings including

> take, hold, or deploy (something) as a means of accomplishing a purpose or achieving a result; employ *she used her key to open the front door*

and

> exploit (a person or situation) for one’s own advantage:
>   *I couldn’t help feeling that she was using me*

When the term means *take advantage of* instead of simply *employ* is not obvious.

> He used her

suggest a mercenary interaction.  However consider it in context:

> She offered to be a resource in accessing her network. He used her.

A neutral (if not positive) connotation.

When the use involves a role that the object is expected to play, it usually is not negative (e.g., the police example). When the role is excessive or one-sided, is usually is negative (e.g., mother doing unnecessary tasks). But context is everything.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case of the 'use and abuse' of the English language.

You are right, in the example you gave, 'use' is used in an exploitative sense.
In this sense, 'use' = abuse.

'I used a metal detector to find the fridge' conveys a different sense entirely.
Here, 'use' = use.